# How do Haskell field labels work?

Tags: haskell

I am looking at [this example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/High-level_option_handling_with_GetOpt) using getOpts, and one portion of it really baffles me: the syntax of field labels.

First, this seems simple enough, creating a data type and declaring the initial values:

```
data Options = Options  { optVerbose    :: Bool
                        , optInput      :: IO String
                        , optOutput     :: String -> IO ()
                        }

startOptions :: Options
startOptions =  Options { optVerbose    = False
                        , optInput      = getContents
                        , optOutput     = putStr
                        }
```

Then `getOpt` is used to go through the options and determine the actual parameters for the running program using a `foldl` command...  and then this let expression frustrates me:

```
let Options { optVerbose = verbose
            , optInput = input
            , optOutput = output   } = opts
```

The boolean and functions `verbose`, `input`, and `output` are then used after this.  In most of the programming languages I'm more familiar with, this step would be written something like so:

```
verbose = opts.optVerbose
input   = opts.optInput
output  = opts.optOutput
```

Is Haskell's behavior here documented someplace?

Comment: Here's a bit of supplementary documentation: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching#Introduction_to_records

Comment: An interesting note: this video with Brendan Eich talking about JavaScript's future shows a slide about "destructuring" with what looks veeeery similar at 11:17 or so.  :) http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/07/brendan-eich-at-jsconf-2010-whats-coming-in-ecmascript-5-and-more/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just normal [pattern-matching](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) — just like when you write `let (x:xs) = someList` and it assigns the first element to `x` and the rest of the list to `xs`.

If you wanted, you could write:

```
let verbose = optVerbose opts
    input   = optInput opts
    output  = optOutput opts
```

Pattern-matching is everywhere in Haskell and the ML family, but not as common in other languages.

Answer (score 6):

This is standard Haskell syntax for defining, setting, and getting values of/from data type defined using records. For instance, in the record

```
data R a = R {v :: a,
              f :: a -> a}
```

a value of type R a can be created, given a value `x :: a` and a function `g :: a -> a`, by

```
r = R {v = x, f = g}
```

Values of fields can be accessed in the following way:

```
get_v :: R a -> a
get_v = v

get_f :: R a -> a -> a
get_f = f,
```

I.e., `get_f = f` and `get_v = v`. Values can be set in a similar manner, using curly brackets:

```
set_v :: R a -> a -> R a
set_v r a = r {v = a}

set_f :: R a -> (a -> a) -> R a
set_f r g = r {f = g}
```

I.e., `set_v` and `set_f` are identical to

```
record {field = value}
```

where `field` is the automatically generated function Haskell provides for access to a record field, and value is the desired value. The values of fields in a data type defined using records can be accessed and set using these operations. The `let` expression in your example is creating a value of type `Options` and setting the values of its fields.

(I'm pretty sure I'm not wrong about this, but if I am...)

Comment: But what is this type `R a`? Obviously the type is just `R`, what is this `a`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the names are just functions to get that data out of the datatype (record). A record is just a datatype with some syntactic sugar to automatically generate functions that can pull data out. I'm not really sure about how it is actually implemented.

You can just apply optVerbose on opts to get the value for optVerbose.

like

```
optVerbose opts
```